# Create new columns based on an existing column. Use 1 or 0

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, split, conditional-statements

Here's the dataframe:

[image]

I want to add 4 new columns (**"business_trip", "leisure", "group",** and **"couple"** in binary format. If the row contains "Business trip," then output 1 for that row in column "business_trip", if not output 0. Same logic for the other columns. Here's an expected output:

[image]

Comment: See, [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html#pandas-series-str-get-dummies)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to create dummies for certain columns by pandas get\_dummies() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265312/how-to-create-dummies-for-certain-columns-by-pandas-get-dummies-method)

Comment: Not quite, in the link you had, it answered how to get dummies for existing two categorical columns. I have only one column, and each row contains multiple strings. I want to create 4 new columns and return 1 or 0 based on whether this row contains that string or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out by myself with the following solution, if you have any other better solutions, please let me know. Thank you!

```
from re import search

def tags(data, tag):
    data[tag] = data['Review_tags'].apply(lambda x: 1 if search(tag, x) else 0)
    return data

tags(df, 'Leisure')
tags(df, 'Business')
tags(df, 'Couple')
tags(df, 'Group')
```

[image]

Comment: I found another way!  `data[tag]  = data['Review_tags'].str.count(tag)`